# In Angularjs, can we remove or neglect case sensitivity in column name in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm having a dropdown data as

```
var listItem = [
    {"name":"Test"},
    {"name":"Berglunds snabbköp"},
    {"name":"Centro comercial Moctezuma"},
    {"name":"Ernst Handel"}
]
```

in the application i'm using this as

```
<select ><option ng-repeat="x in records">{{x.name}}</<option></select>
```

here my question is we are writing in the option as **x.name**, can we write as 
**x.Name** because when i'm writing as **x.Name** its not displaying values. so is there any possibility of neglecting this case sensitivity.

i may be wrong in asking like this but out of curiosity.

Comment: Object properties are strings and they are case sensitive. so you cannot but you can write your own methods to achieve this. But won't recommend. You can make standard to follow certain naming conventions, and use them.

Answer (score 0):

The straight answer is **NO**.

As a workaround, [you can try something like this](https://plnkr.co/edit/hmJACAN8HYY6IdQ2LavD?p=preview).

I strongly suggest you not to do such workarounds:

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="x in records">
      {{x['Name'.toLowerCase()]}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is variables, objects and properties are case sensitive so we can not access in-case sensitive names. If we try to access any variables or properties in object, we need to give correct name otherwise it return value as *undefined*

Answer (score 0):

JS is case sensitive, but you can still display it with a small hack:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    {"name":"AAA"},
    {"Name":"BBB"},
    {"name":"CCC"},
    {"Name":"DDD"}
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select>
    <option ng-repeat="x in records">
      {{x.name}}{{x.Name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

If one of the `x.name` or `x.Name` is undefined it will show the other instead.